# How can I solve this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

Tags: jquery, error-handling, requirejs, magento2

I am using the module for SMS Notifications in Magento 2, which is affecting another module used to hide price. 
When I am trying to open Hide price dashboard, I m getting this error.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at smsnotification.js?v=6688:1
jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:14075 Uncaught TypeError: ui.jqXHR.success is not a function
    at $.<computed>.<computed>.tabsbeforeload (jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:14075)
    at HTMLDivElement.handlerProxy (jquery-ui-1.9.2.js:739)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js?v=6688:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.q.handle (jquery.min.js?v=6688:3)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js?v=6688:4)
    at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (jquery-migrate.js:493)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js?v=6688:4)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js?v=6688:2)
    at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js?v=6688:2)
    at jQuery.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js?v=6688:4)
```

I tried to add requirejs code but it didnt work. I m sharing here js file code. from TEXT_Smsnotifications module.
the path in cpanel is

domain_file/app/code/TEXT/Smsnotifications/view/adminhtml/web/js/smsnotification.js

'''

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".click-me").click(function(){

   jQuery("#popup-mpdal").addClass('open-popop');
 });

   jQuery(".close-popop").click(function(){

   jQuery("#popup-mpdal").removeClass('open-popop');
 });});
```

'''
I have also added min.js in script.
domain_name/app/code/TEXT/Smsnotifications/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <head>
          <css src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" src_type="url" />
          <script src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::js/smsnotification.js" />
          <css src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::css/smsnotification.css" />
       </head> 
     </page>
```

Expected Result: After enabling SMS notification module also Another module named Hide Price should work finely.

Actual Result: After enabling SMS notification module, Hide price is not opening tab in Admin Dashboard of Magento 2.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined - usually means that the jquery library is not loaded. include it frm a CDN - <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> or locally  - <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

Comment: make sure you include jquery Script

Comment: can u elaborate?

Comment: I have already added that in /domain_name/app/code/TEXT/Smsnotifications/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0"?> <page xmlns:xsi="w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd"> <head> <css src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::css/bootstrap.min.css"/> <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" src_type="url" /> <script src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::js/smsnotification.js" /> <css src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::css/smsnotification.css" /> </head> </page>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this before any other dependent script tags (in the header).

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.*.*.min.js"></script>
```

replace * with your required JQuery version

Comment: '''<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_layout.xsd">
       <head>
          <css src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::css/bootstrap.min.css"/> 
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" src_type="url" />
          <script src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::js/smsnotification.js" />
          <css src="TEXT_Smsnotifications::css/smsnotification.css" />
       </head> 
     </page>'''

Comment: I have already added that in /domain_name/app/code/TEXT/Smsnotifications/view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml